# Clojure IDE on Windows?

Tags: windows, ide, clojure

How do you develop in Clojure on Windows systems?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Personally I use emacs because no other IDE feels right with sexpression languages to me.  Swank/slime/emacs/clojure is just such a powerful repl setup nothing else feels right to me.  If you want it set up easily (assuming you don't already have emacs set up) check out clojurebox

https://github.com/devinus/clojure-box

Preconfigged to just work on windows after running an installer.

Comment: What do you use for build, test, and deploy? That's always the hidden kicker in choosing a language.

Comment: These days I code in Linux VMs funny enough, because many of the best tools feel better there (Lein covers most/all of what you asked about, and works on windows supposedly but when I tried it in the early days it wasn't so good, so can't comment on now)

Comment: Lein works well on Windows now. The usual caveats for Windows development using tools first written on Linux apply (i.e. it's not a bad idea to put your work in a filepath without spaces, etc.)

Comment: The Clojure Box link is broken.

Answer (score 17):

On the site, the first thing you would read when [getting started](http://clojure.org/getting_started) lists all your current options.
There is a [netbeans add-in](http://enclojure.org/), [emacs mode](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/4a920f3b1d5d9234) and [vim syntax](http://repo.or.cz/w/clojure-patches.git?a=blob_plain;f=vim/clojure.vim;hb=HEAD) highlighting.

Comment: That getting started page links to this detailed page, which has been relocated to here: [Getting Started](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Getting+Started). It contains summaries of how to get going with a number of editors and build tools.

Answer (score 15):

There is also an eclipse plug-in here: http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/

**Edit:** changed link per js' comment

Comment: now: http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise

Answer (score 12):

[Enclojure](http://Enclojure.org) (in Netbeans) is now released and works well on Windows.

[VimClojure](http://kotka.de/projects/clojure/vimclojure.html) is a good lightweight solution.

Answer (score 8):

I don't. I'm waiting on the release of Enclojure, the netbeans plugin that fixes some of the windows problems.

UPDATE: I do now, Enclojure ROCKS! :D

Answer (score 8):

Another interesting IDE under development is a project funded through Kickstarter.com, the Light Table IDE:
http://app.kodowa.com/playground

The IDE is heavily inspired by the concepts [Bret Victor](http://worrydream.com/) presented at CUSEC 2012: [Inventing on Principle](http://vimeo.com/36579366)

Chris Granger felt so inspired by Bret's ideas, that he quickly put together a [proof-of-concept for a new Clojure](http://www.chris-granger.com/2012/04/12/light-table---a-new-ide-concept/) IDE, which he calls Light Table. The project got [$300k of funding through Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/306316578/light-table), and very early releases of the IDE are available through the project playground. Installation is as easy as a single download and click, if you have Java and Chrome installed on your system.

The IDE is in a very early stage, but has some very distinctive features, especially the "live" view of your code in the right panel. Check this screenshot of Light Table running in Chrome:

[image: Light Table IDE running in Chrome browser on Windows]

Answer (score 6):

I have been experimenting with Clojure last two months and in my 
learning process I used several applications.

So, I have made a package and want it to share it with everybody that 
want to learn Clojure. 
What's wrong with the existing Clojure Box? well... nothing at all; 
but if you are like me and want to avoid the complexity of learning a 
new programming language in a new ide (for me) like emacs you may be 
find this package useful.

You have a customized version of scite, an application named 
WinCommand to work more confortable with Clojure repl and JSwat to 
debug your code.

Remember that WinCommand is developed using .Net framework (VS 2008) 
but it was developed 4-5 years ago and my programming skills wasn't 
the bests, so if you find something that can be fixed you can suggest 
me.

Give it a try and let me know what do you think about it!

Ahh...jejeje... well.. if you want to download it you can find here: 
http://sites.google.com/site/dariomac/Home/projects

Comment: Now I kick off JSwat and only publish the editor...

Answer (score 5):

Jetbrains recently released "La Clojure", a Clojure plugin for their already excellent (but commercial) Java IDE IntelliJ IDEA.  Once you have IDEA installed you can install the plugin from the plugin manager, or download it from [the plugin website.](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4050)

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use [VimClojure](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2501) but found it uninviting.  I'm a Vim person, but the idea that I have to compile my editor before even trying it out is definitely not what I'm looking for.  The fact that the author says he doesn't care about Windows support any more adds to my disinclination to use it.  On top of that, the documentation is pretty poor.

I'm attracted to [ClojureBox](http://clojure.bighugh.com/) which is Clojure and Emacs in an easy-to-use installer.  Maybe it's time to give Emacs another shot.  It comes right up in the REPL.

Comment: I got it to work on vanilla gvim on Windows without any compilation.

Answer (score 2):

[Clooj](https://github.com/arthuredelstein/clooj/) is good for learning.  Not, probably, a practical IDE for real development — for that I'd use Emacs — but it's a perfect way to get started with no complex setup.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone new to clojure like I am. Intellij + Cursive seems to be very friendly to newbie.
Link: https://cursive-ide.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use Lighttable to develop Clojure apps. Its pretty fantastic! I would recommend.

Comment: I use Nightcode for small apps. It's super useful for beginners. https://sekao.net/nightcode/

Comment: lately, I've been using Atom with proto-repl package. It's been really good, can't complain.