# ClojureBox initialization Warning

Tags: clojure

When I run [Clojure Box](http://clojure.bighugh.com/) it gives me the following error

```
"Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `~/.emacs':

File error: Searching for program, no such file or directory, java

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace."
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us what's in your `~/.emacs` file?

Comment: I am running it on windows. I really don't know what " ~/.emacs "means. :(

Comment: Sorry I missed that Clojure Box was a Windows setup. I've provided an answer that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Clojure Box is a Windows Clojure setup. It looks like you don't have Java installed yet. You'll need to install the Windows JDK from Oracle first:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html

Comment: well, I had an issue with Eclipse so I uninstalled my 32bit JRE+JDK and reinstalled 64bit of those. Is it ok to install 32bit of JDK over these? Any possibility of conflict?

Comment: @iamcreasy You may want to try restarting then, as it could be that your windows environment hasn't been updated yet, so your setup can't see the java executable.

Comment: But in command line java is accessible from anywhere.I guess that means java executable is set in windows environment.

There is another issue, when i run ClojureBox, there is a "Emacs Client" trys to start Emacs Server, but after trying several attempts, is says "Error Timeout waiting for server"

ClojureBox ran ok when I had 32Bit JDK installed, and this Server connection error wasn't posing any issue on that time.

Comment: @iamcreasy That's unfortunately something that would have to be run past whoever provides ClojureBox, as I don't have enough knowledge about how it binds the individual components. You may want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463776/clojure-ide-on-windows as well to see other solutions for Windows.